# Unexpected python counter value

Tags: python, python-3.5

The output value of code is cnt['yellow'] = zero but the expected value after applying the formula given in the code should be (0 +1)/(6 + (1*3))

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
sm = 1
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
    cnt[word] += 1

s = sum(cnt.values())
print(s)

c = len(cnt)
print(c)

for k,v in cnt.items():
    cnt[k] = (cnt[k] + sm)/(s + (sm *c))

print(cnt['yellow'])
```

Comment: Are you *sure* this is Python 3.5?

Comment: Actually, `'yellow'` isn't in your input at all. You're getting the default count. There's nothing here that would apply your `cnt[k] = (cnt[k] + sm)/(s + (sm *c))` computation to `cnt['yellow']`.

Comment: I want to change this default zero to something positive by this computation.Is there anything I can do.

Comment: Please if anyone can share the work around this problem to manipulate the default value of counter without using a class.It will be great help.

Answer (score 1):

To apply a function , to any entered value, you could use a class and method , 
that would be elegant way , I don't know your program , but you may rename the class for better readability , according to what it actually represent like this (this is tested in py2 but should work in py3):

```
from collections import Counter
lst1 = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']

class count_helper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sm = 1.0
        self.cnt = Counter()

    def count_colors(self,lst):
        for w in lst:
            self.cnt[w]+=1.0

    def __call__(self,color='blank'):
        s = sum(self.cnt.values())
        c = len(self.cnt)
        return (self.cnt[color] + self.sm)/(s + (self.sm *c))

cntc = count_helper()
cntc.count_colors(lst1)
print(cntc('yellow'))
```

**Result:**

```
0.111111111111
```

And :

```
In [13]: print(cntc('red'))
0.333333333333

In [14]: print(cntc('blue'))
0.444444444444
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason of using object oriented programming to get the desired result

Comment: you needed a way to execute function for any input ( a function ) yet , your counter object must save other values, ( your list ).. /you could save the counter independently, but that would be ugly/ , more elegant form is to envelope it inside other bigger object, which one of his methods is to print the requested formula, I'll update my answer , to emphasis this .

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom method like:

```
def getCount(counter, key):
  sm = 1
  s = sum(cnt.values())
  c = len(cnt)
  return (counter[key] + sm)/(s + (sm * c))
```

And then use it by calling:

```
print getCount(cnt, "yellow")
```